# Load external html content with jquery - with latin extended characters

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, encoding, escaping

I have small jquery script which allows me to load external html content by clicking to Li element which has ID equal such as part of content in HTML file which is loaded into specific div as result **but I have problems with encoding** (extended latin characters). Does anyone knows how to solve this problem.

Below is link on non-working JSFiddle because i can`t load contents in JSFiddle from my server but everything is there.

Here is JSFiDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/QQz5W/

Part of code which missing from fiddle is actually html file which need to be loaded and which contains text with latin extended characters.

Here is that part:

```
 <div id="section_first">
        <div class="LeftDiv">
            <h2>Opći uvjeti za montiranje drvenih podnih obloga</h2>
        </div>

            <h3>1. PRIJE POLAGANJA</h3>
            <p><b>1.1. Dozvoljena vlažnost podloge:</b><br>
            - cementna košuljica do 2,0%, cementna košuljica s podnim grijanjem do 1,8%<br>
            - anhidridna košuljica do 0,5%, anhidridna košuljica s podnim grijanjem do 0,3%<br>
            - ploče od iverice 9+4% / 8+2%</p>
    </div>
<div id="section_second">
        <div class="LeftDiv">
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </div>
<p><b>bla bla čćšđž ČĆŽŠĐ</b></p>
    </div>
```

I`ve tried to add

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta content="hr" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
</head>
```

to that html file but it seems that this part is ignored on load.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant HTML with the Latin-1 chars please?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it is written here in my question. Just to note that this jquery script calls part of code in that HTML file (in this case #section_first from test.html file)

Comment: you know that there is no `proizvodi` variable defined anywhere.. right ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli it is defined for different pages proizvodi.click(function(){
for file proizvodi.html
and so one

Comment: Yes.. i mean in the example that the `proizvodi` variable is not yet defined when you try to bind the click method..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli that`s right...here proizvodi variable is not defined. Can you point me how to get working extended latin characters in loaded content?

Comment: @Marko by default, the Latin characters will be decoded. What's the `charset` default for you? is it not already UTF-8?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy By default it is set to UTF-8 but content which is loaded is plain html without any HEAD tags. I`ve tried to add head tags to this plain html file which is loaded to site frontend but head tags are rejected on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to loading content (try utf-8 or ISO-8859-1):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.html #section_first",

    /* VERY IMPORTANT */
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",// or ISO-8859-1

    success: function(data){
           content.html(data);        
           hideLoading();           
    }
});
```